# Ansible - Read a file, extract specific line, extract a column and assign to variable

Tags: list, ansible, lookup

I need some help with extracting a specific line from a file and then extracting a column,  assign it to a variable and then use that variable in the next task.

I have the file with this format on the confluent broker server

```
Save the key. It cannot be retrieved later.
+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Enc Key | omykeyvaluecontinuousstringgoeshereandmakelong= |
+------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to write Ansible task that will read the third line and then extract the key into  a variable which I need to export as an environment variable in the task.   In the next task I will be executing a confluent command as a shell command.

I tried something like below, but it doesn't work - I get error

```
vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    ansible_host_key_checking: false
    contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/kafka/info.txt') }}"
    contents2: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/kafka/info.txt').splitlines() }}"

- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    extract_key: "{{ contents.split('\n')[2] }}"

- name: Display output
  debug: msg="{{ extract_key }}"
```

And then extract the key value from extract_key variable

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You can look at the `regexp_replace` filter to extract a part of a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        extract_key: "{{ contents.split('\n').2.split('|').2|trim }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  extract_key: omykeyvaluecontinuousstringgoeshereandmakelong=
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this filter if only text lines are fixed:

```
- name: capturing Key
  shell: echo {{ contents }} | head -3 | tail -1 | sed 's/|/\n/g' | sed -n 3p
  register: extract_key

- name: Display output
  debug: msg="{{ extract_key.stdout }}"
```

This returns **omykeyvaluecontinuousstringgoeshereandmakelong=**

Comment: This also works.  I was trying to fix the syntax - to add quotes around the {{ contents }} - It seems I don't have access to edit.  You may want to make that change